# Magento Redirecting to Dashboard on Save in Back-End, Changes Lost

Tags: magento2, backend, cookie, save, dashboard

I have an intermittent issue that seems to happen across all of the Magento 2 sites I manage where if I'm working in the back-end and I save something (could be a content block, category, product, etc), from time to time it will redirect me to the dashboard and I'll lose all of the work I was saving. This happens to me almost once a day, and it often times happens soon after logging in so I don't know how it could be cookie related (since our cookie lifetime is set to one hour). Has anyone else run into this issue? As you can image, it's terribly frustrating, and it's gotten to the point where I select and copy all content I've edited before clicking save so that I can paste it in, if the save action doesn't work.

Any suggestions on what to look at?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)
```

Also there is a possibility to set this parameter directly to database, just put a value under path

> admin/security/session_lifetime

in the table core_config_data

Update

> Magento 2.1 admin cookie life time = Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds) or till the user closes the browser

Since Magento 2.1 introduces lifetime for admin cookie as "expires on browser close", together with value in

```
Stores >Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)
```

That means, that session life time equals value in

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)
```

run the command :-

```
rm -rf var/cache
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

this is my suggestion but not sure but you try this :-

your are multi store website so you change the any css changes and run the deploy command

Answer (score 0):

Check your php settings.
By default max_input_vars is 1000 which is not enough when you have per example several custom options.

Try to change to max_input_vars = 10000, restart httpd, apache, fpm (the one that applies in your server) and try again.